# Why Python configuration library's public variables did not change as I feed private variable to them

Tags: python, private, public

I was planning to create a Python library as configuration file.

I expect to let users change private variables in configuration, then when the config file run its load_input() function, these private variables will be verified and those correspondent variables will has their values.

But when I import this config file, it seems like its public variables have not been changed. Could you tell me the reasons?

Thank you guys very much. Here is the config file below.

```
    # config.py

    __level1_fullpath = '.../level_1a.csv'
    __boundary_fullpath = '.../TLS_adm0.shp'
    __output_polygon_fullpath = 'TEST_hightlight_USA.shp'
    __output_point_fullpath = 'Test_highlight_USA_point.shp'

    __attribute_csv_fullpath = 'default'
    __dict_filter = {}
    __dict_filter['donors_iso3'] = 'USA'
    __time_filter = {}
    # __time_filter['example'] = {'start':2006, 'end':2010}
    __voronoi_mode = 1
    __allow_empty_time_record = False
    __comparing_country_iso = ''

    level1_fullpath = None
    boundary_fullpath = None
    output_polygon_fullpath = None
    output_point_fullpath = None
    attribute_csv_fullpath = None
    # for time filter:
    # boolean
    allow_empty_time_record = None
    # voronoi mode
    voronoi_mode = None
    # two kinds of filters
    dict_filter = None
    time_filter = None
    # pairwise mode must have this input below
    comparing_country_iso = None

    def load_input():
    try:
        level1_fullpath = str(__level1_fullpath)
        boundary_fullpath = str(__boundary_fullpath)
        output_point_fullpath = str(__output_point_fullpath)
        output_polygon_fullpath = str(__output_polygon_fullpath)
        attribute_csv_fullpath = str(__attribute_csv_fullpath)
    except:
        raise ImportError('Please check all input fullpath parameters are writen correctly in Input Configuration file')

    try:
        dict_filter = dict(__dict_filter)
        time_filter = dict(__time_filter)
    except:
        raise ImportError('Please check filter dictionray has been inputted properly in input configuration file.')

    try:
        voronoi_mode = int(__voronoi_mode)
    except:
        raise ImportError('Please check __voronoi_mode has been inputted properly under instruction.')

    try:
         allow_empty_time_record = bool(__allow_empty_time_record)
    execpt:
        raise ImportError('Please check __allow_empty_time_record has been inputted properly under instruction.')

    try:
        if voronoi_mode == 2:
            comparing_country_iso = str(__comparing_country_iso)
    except:
        raise ImportError('Please check __comparing_counties_iso has been inputted properly under instruction.')

    load_input()
```

And when I try to import it and use configuration variables. I will do like this

```
    import config

    inputdata = config.level1_fullpath
    voronoi_mode = config.voronoi_mode
    ...
```

But these public variables just shown None, being NoneType.

Comment: You'll have to define the variables as [`global`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) in your `load_input` function.

Comment: @Rawing, Thank you very much. In the function, I claim these values as global values and it works !